# How to Deserialize XML in c# having child nodes of same type

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I need to deserialize bellow XML. The chapter element can have multiple child chapter element in it.I have tried to deserialize the XML using XmlSerializer.
All the elements are deserializing as expected but the issue is that the child Chapter array is not deserializing, am I missing something here? Please help.

```
<Survey>
        <SurveyResults>
            <Subject>
                <Chapter>
                    <ChapterIterationName />
                    <Questions />
                    <Chapter>
                        <ChapterName>CHAPTER 1</ChapterName>
                        <ChapterIterationName />
                        <Questions>
                            <Question>
                                <Text>Question 1</Text>
                            </Question>
                            <Question>
                                <Text>Question 2</Text>
                            </Question>
                        </Questions>
                        <Chapter>
                            <ChapterName>CHAPTER 1.1</ChapterName>
                            <ChapterIterationName />
                            <Questions>
                                <Question>
                                    <Text>Questoin 1</Text>
                                </Question>
                                <Question>
                                    <Text>Questoin 2</Text>
                                </Question>
                            </Questions>
                        </Chapter>
                        <Chapter>
                            <ChapterName>CHAPTER 1.2</ChapterName>
                            <ChapterIterationName />
                            <Questions>
                                <Question>
                                    <Text>Questoin 1</Text>
                                </Question>
                                <Question>
                                    <Text>Questoin 2</Text>
                                </Question>
                            </Questions>
                        </Chapter>
                    </Chapter>
                </Chapter>
            </Subject>
        </SurveyResults>
    </Survey>
```

Here is the code I have tried.

```
public class Survey
    { 
        public SurveyResults SurveyResults { get; set; }
    }

    public class SurveyResults
    {
        public Subject Subject { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subject
    { 
        public List<Chapter> Chapter { get; set; }
    }

    public class Chapter
    {
        public string ChapterName { get; set; }
        public string ChapterIterationName { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Chapter")]
        public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
        public List<Questions> Questions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Questions
    {
         public List<Question> Question { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public string Text { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Serializer
    { 
        public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            {
                return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }
    }

    Serializer ser = new Serializer();
    Survey survey = ser.Deserialize<Survey>(xlString);
```

Result 
[image: Output]

Comment: Why do you have `List<Questions> Questions` in `Chapter` instead of direct `List<Question> Questions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edit]**

After so many edits, I found the simple way to solve this:

1. Copy you XML file contents.
2. From Visual Studio Menus select **Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes**.
3. Use the deserialize code.

   ```
       string path = @"G:\Projects\StackOverFlow\WpfApp1\Survey.xml";
       FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(path);
       XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Survey));
       Survey survey = (Survey)ser.Deserialize(reader);
   ```

Comment: not working, Child Chapters are not there & Question Count = 0. Have updated the question with the Output.

Comment: @KousiK I edited my answer, now it works. Have a look!

Comment: There is no element called <Chapters>. The element <Chapter> is nested to another <Chapter>. I am not creating the XML, I am getting the xml from third party.

Comment: Oh. I thought you created it. My mistake again :)

Comment: @Bassed Akl, I just need to parse the xml file to a C# object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160996/discussion-between-bassem-akl-and-kousik).